# Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store is currently unavailable in Sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

When I click on "External Content Types" in the Navigation pane of Sharepoint Designer 2013, I get the error message "The Business Data Connectivity Metadata Store is currently unavailable".  What is causing this?

[image: Error message]